# Some doubt on crossed product von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There are two definitions in different books. Let $G \curvearrowright M$, then there is the definition of forming Group ring $M[G]$, define product and addition then make its algebra. represent the copy of group and Vn algebra $M$ in the Hilbert space take the S.O.T closure. In van dale book general construction is given but I want to know how to think about Fourier series and like the covariant system $\{x\otimes 1, \lambda_{g}\otimes u_{g}\}''$, these two definitions how they are equivalent? If a start with a state on $M$, what is the GNS space of crossed product?

Comment: What is a reference for your first definition?

Comment: Popa's book 1st defn @Daws

Comment: Which book?  What page?  I am looking at the draft of the book with Anantharaman, page 65.  This seems to be the "usual" definition, acting on $\ell^2(G, L^2(M))$.

Comment: yes 65, Anathram Popa book; why we can write any element of the crossed product in terms of Fourier series, the same Fourier series analog is written by a paper of Ioana